# Not able to View Message in Messages

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I got a notification regarding a message from a Recruiter. When I clicked on it, It redirected to the Messages page. But the page is empty. No messages are shown.

When I opened the chrome debugger, the following errors were there. Looks like Angular app failed to initialise.

Script from origin 'http://ajax.googleapis.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://stackoverflow.com' is therefore not allowed access.
5/jobs/messages?userId=163384/#!/inbox/1527850:1 Script from origin 'http://cdn.sstatic.net' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://stackoverflow.com' is therefore not allowed access.
user-messaging.min.js?v=2ac921bbc56a:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
messages?userId=163384/:804 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

Comment: Your browser is not receiving the CORS headers (you can see it's having issues loading from `ajax.googleapis.com`) _probably_ due to an extension removing them (this is the 3rd report about the same issue actually). Can you try running the curl command in [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335350/920295)? If that gets you the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, then try it on a different browser and let me know ;) we'll figure it out