# Editing my education in profile CV leads to getting JSON data

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow-jobs

I tried to edit my CV, specifically the Education section, editing an existing element. Once I added data I clicked on save and the following page was a JSON object getting printed.

[image]

The data was actually saved (next time I reloaded CV, updated data was shown). I'm using FF48 on Manjaro Linux.

Edit: The following errors and warnings show up when loading the edit page.

[image]

The request headers and the response are as follows

[image]

[image]

Edit: Response headers for Sanitizer js file are as follows:

```
Accept-Ranges    bytes 
Age  3006 
Cache-Control    max-age=604800
Connection   keep-alive 
Content-Length   1158 
Content-Type application/javascript 
Date     Tue, 27 Sep 2016 15:22:08 GMT 
Etag "e93da3b4cb18d21:0" 
Last-Modified    Tue, 27 Sep 2016 14:30:33 GMT 
Vary Accept-Encoding 
Via  1.1 varnish
```

***Edit***: After a continuous effort (and many, many emails), I got IT checking firewall parameters and now I got my response headers in all their glory. Now, my CV is not being translated to json-ish. Thanks!

Comment: Probably something to do with the Developer Story?

Comment: It's a feature.

Comment: This is a buggy week!

Comment: This is a test of your programming skillz, which clearly you failed.  You'll never get a job now.  You were supposed to read the json, convert it to XML, reverse it, hash it, and submit that via ajax from IE 6 using polycryptonic encryption channels.  Everyone knows that.

Comment: @Alfabravo We're having trouble reproducing the bug. Do you have any browser extensions? And how did you submit the form -- clicking the "Save" button or hitting Enter on one of the fields?

Comment: @SteveTrout I have firebug and web developer extensions but I disabled them to test at the time of editing and it keeps showing the json. Also, it happens when I click on Save button and when I hit enter having the focus on one of the fields.

Comment: @CaptainHypertext maybe the SO's HTML parser based on regex failed...

Comment: @Alfabravo thanks. I'm still having no luck reproducing it. The code should be submitting the form as an ajax request, but somehow it's doing a plain old submit in your case. Do you see any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: @SteveTrout edited the question with some screenshots.

Comment: @Alfabravo is this still happening for you? what does `ping cdn.sstatic.net` return for you? thanks!

Comment: I could use the help of anyone else also experiencing this issue, just get me the result of `ping cdn.sstatic.net` ;) thanks!

Comment: @GervasioMarchand one of the screenshots shows it's related to CORS so cdn.sstatic.net resources are blocked [(see this)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24182259/cross-origin-request-blocked-the-same-origin-policy-disallows-reading-the-remot#24200871). That SO question says something about adding a header so no CSRF filter gets triggered. ALSO, I tried editing on a different machine, different network (FF49 on windows, other network) and it worked ok. :/

Comment: @Alfabravo yes, I'm actually writing a response explaining what I _think_ happened... is this still an issue for you? if it is, please get me that IP ;)

Comment: @GervasioMarchand also, on the machine and connection where it fails, ping does work. Filtering happens up in the stack

Comment: @Alfabravo you are correct, the filtering is done by Firefox... what I'm seeing is that some CDN servers are sending back that header and that others don't... that's why I'd need your help to verify if this is still an issue, and if it is, I need you to get me the IP of the server your machine is connecting to when it queries these files.

Comment: One of the screenshots shows the cookies. Somebody could probably hijack your session with that. I recommend [logging out](http://stackoverflow.com/users/logout) on all devices to invalidate your current session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your logs, I see that your browser didn't really load various Javascript files due to a CORS header missing (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`) from `cdn.sstatic.net`. All of us who weren't able to reproduce the issue are receiving `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

What I was able to verify, is that the lack of that header is consistent with the issue you are facing (I did get to see that beautiful JSON after updating the CV), but I haven't been able to pinpoint *when/why/if* that header isn't sent by our servers.

Try running these commands to verify what you get (the leading hypothesis right now is that something in your network may be doing funny things with the headers)

**Test 1** (http)

```
curl -v 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/careers/Js/StackExchange.Sanitizer.min.js?v=d436379d3d2b' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Host: cdn.sstatic.net' -H 'Origin: http://stackoverflow.com' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0' -o /dev/null
```

**Test 2** (https)

```
curl -v 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/careers/Js/StackExchange.Sanitizer.min.js?v=d436379d3d2b' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Host: cdn.sstatic.net' -H 'Origin: http://stackoverflow.com' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0' -o /dev/null
```

Comment: $ ping cdn.sstatic.net
PING cdn.sstatic.net (151.101.193.69) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 151.101.193.69 (151.101.193.69): icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=128 ms

Comment: @Alfabravo I've verified that the `151.101.193.69` server is now returning `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. If you clear your cache, is this something you're still facing?

Comment: Tried again on the machine where it fails. Cleared cache on browser , reloaded, got HTTP 200 but still shows same errors and warnings on console. Also, no nice extra headers on responses :/

Comment: On the network tab of firebug, can you show me the response headers of `StackExchange.Sanitizer.min.js`? also, that machine also resolves `cdn.sstatic.net` to `151.101.193.69`, right?

Comment: Response headers added to question. And yes, firebug says remote IP is that one. For other resources (jquery, analytics), it says it's .129.69. On the main CV page, after clearing cache, I get many CORS messages on console as well and the cdn Ip is 151.101.1.69.

Comment: @Alfabravo you're missing a bunch of headers (the `X-Cache` and the `Access-Control` ones). Do you have a proxy in your company that could be tweakig them? try running `curl -v 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/careers/Js/StackExchange.Sanitizer.min.js?v=d436379d3d2b' -o /dev/null` on the machine where it fails and check if the IP is that one and if the missing headers are in there

Comment: I'm getting HTTP 400 trying that curl :/ but also, I'm asking if we're filtering that on the network where it's failing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124323/discussion-between-gervasio-marchand-and-alfabravo).

Comment: @Alfabravo it definitely looks like there's something in your network that's filtering requests, it's not our server who's replying with that 400 error... maybe this would work for you `curl -v 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/careers/Js/StackExchange.Sanitizer.min.js?v=d436379d3d2b' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Host: cdn.sstatic.net' -H 'Origin: http://stackoverflow.com' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0' -o /dev/null`

Comment: @GervasioMarchand The URL you posted in the comments is actually Bad. SO inserts invisible special symbols (delimiters) into long words in the comments, which _breaks_ the URL.

Comment: Thanks @Roman, that's absolutely right (and probably the reason why Alfabravo was getting that 400 error). I've tweaked my response with that issue fixed

Comment: @Roman You are right. I tried the new request in Gervasio's answer and  I get HTTP 200 but I'm not getting the header. Still asking people at my workplace about this.

Comment: @Alfabravo can you run the test 2 on this answer? We may get away with switching the links to https

Comment: Edited question. Marked it as solved, thanks!