# Bug while editing and saving CV

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

1. In the Edit CV Option, I choose a section and click edit. 
   [image: 1. In Edit CV Option, I choose a section and click edit.]

2. Edit a section, and click on Save, 
[image: 2. Click on Save]

2. The resulting screen is 
[image: The resulting screen is]

Adding console log for additional info. 
[image]

Header for StackExchange.Sanitizer.min.js request

[image]

Comment: Can you please include your javascript console? I'm particularly interested in any errors being shown. Also, please execute that `curl` command and show me the output (or on the network tab of your developer tools, check the headers for StackExchange.Sanitizer.min.js)

Comment: Thanks! this is super interesting... it seems like you're not receiving the CORS headers, but what's more interesting is that you're having the same issue with `ajax.googleapis.com`. Can you execute the `curl` command on [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335350/920295) and show me the output you get?

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Content-Type: application/javascript
Last-Modified: Thu, 29 Sep 2016 08:48:28 GMT
ETag: "5deca63f2e1ad21:0"
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with
Access-Control-Max-Age: 60
Content-Length: 1158
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Thu, 29 Sep 2016 14:18:00 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Age: 101
Connection: keep-alive
X-Served-By: cache-jfk8146-JFK
X-Cache: HIT
X-Cache-Hits: 1
X-Timer: S1475158680.380587,VS0,VE0
Vary: Accept-Encoding

Comment: Thanks! that means you have nothing on your network stripping the headers... specially this one `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` (that you can see is missing in the response your browser shows you). Can you try in an incognito mode (where all the extensions are disabled by default)? if the page works in incognito, we have an extension to blame (if incognito works and you can get me a list of your installed extensions that would be great)

Comment: Thanx @GervasioMarchand, will look into it and update you.

Comment: Pkease share your findings so that we can work out a solution on our end or with the extension developer. Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to figure it out? on the other user's case, it was an issue in their network firewall. Thanks!